# I want to detect ranges with the same numerical boundaries of a dataset using matplotlib or pandas in python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a ton of ranges. They all consist of numbers. The range has a maximum and a minimum which can not be exceeded, but given the example that you have two ranges and one **max** point of the range reaches above the **min** area of the other. That would mean that you have a small area that covers both of them. You can write one range that includes the others.

I want to see if some ranges overlap or if I can find some ranges that cover most of the other. The goal would be to see if I can simplify them by using one smaller range that fits inside the other. For example 7,8 - 9,6 and 7,9 - 9,6 can be covered with one range.

You can see my attempt to visualize them. But when I use my entire dataset consisting of hundreds of ranges my graph is not longer useful.

I know that I can detect recurrent ranges using python. But I don't want to know how often a range occurs. I want to know how many ranges lay in the same numerical boundaries.I want see if I can have a couple of ranges covering all of them. Finally my goal is to have the masterranges sorted in categories. Meaning that I have range 1 covering 50 other ranges. then range 2 covering 25 ranges and so on.

My current program shows the penetration of ranges but I also want that in a printed output with the exact digits.

It would be nice if you share some ideas to solve that program or if you have any suggestions on tools within python 3.7

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intervals = [[3.6,4.5],
[3.6,4.5],
[7.8,9.6],
[7.9,9.6],
[7.8,9.6],
[3.4,4.1],
[2.8,3.4],

[8.25,9.83],
[3.62,3.96],
[8.25,9.83],
[0.62,0.68],
[2.15,2.49],

[0.8,1.0],
[0.8,1.0],
[3.1,3.9],
[6.7,8.3],

[1,1.5],
[1,1.2],
[1.5,1.8],
[1.8,2.5],
[3,4.0],
[6.5,8.0],

[1.129,1.35],
[2.82,3.38],
[1.69,3.38],
[3.38,6.21],
[2.25,2.82],
[5.649,6.214],
[1.920,6.214]
]

for int in intervals:
    plt.plot(int,[0,0], 'b', alpha = 0.2, linewidth = 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, You make a pandas data frame with the array. You substract the values in column2 - colum1  ( column 1 is x, and column 2 is y ). After that you create a histogram in which you take the range and the frecuency.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

intervals = [[3.6,4.5],
[3.6,4.5],
[7.8,9.6],
[7.9,9.6],
[7.8,9.6],
[3.4,4.1],
[2.8,3.4],

[8.25,9.83],
[3.62,3.96],
[8.25,9.83],
[0.62,0.68],
[2.15,2.49],

[0.8,1.0],
[0.8,1.0],
[3.1,3.9],
[6.7,8.3],

[1,1.5],
[1,1.2],
[1.5,1.8],
[1.8,2.5],
[3,4.0],
[6.5,8.0],

[1.129,1.35],
[2.82,3.38],
[1.69,3.38],
[3.38,6.21],
[2.25,2.82],
[5.649,6.214],
[1.920,6.214]]

intervals_ar = np.array(intervals)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': intervals_ar[:, 0], 'Column2': intervals_ar[:, 1]})
df['Ranges'] = df['Column2'] - df ['Column1']
print(df)

frecuency_range = df['Ranges'].value_counts().sort_index()
print(frecuency_range)

df.Ranges.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind = 'hist', bins = 5)
plt.title("Histogram Frecuency vs Range (column 2- column1)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your support. A very interesting approach to the  problem. I had to dig deeper to understand what you meant. It works perfectly for my example. But if I enter my entire dataset I get an error ```too many indices for array```. Do you know how to geet along with this error?

Comment: ```---> 89 df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': intervals_ar[:, 0], 'Column2': intervals_ar[:, 1]})
     90 df['Ranges'] = df['Column2'] - df ['Column1']
     91 print(df)

IndexError: too many indices for array```

Comment: That warning means that when you are making the dataframe in this case for example : ypu have multiple 2D array  array = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]... . Since it is not a memory problem I would suggest cleaning your data, I am almost positive that in one of the intervals array elements you are missing a comma between the x and y

Comment: Or maybe a comma between intervasl [x,y] [x1,y1] <---- missing comma